# nextLine ignored in Java when asking for input

Tags: java, file-io

Below you will see some code that I am having trouble with. The basic idea is a simple copy of one existing text file to a new one, but if the new one exists, you are given three options. The other switch cases work flawlessly, but this third and final case does not work as I want it to at all!

Basically this is the choice that lets you pick a new file name if the previously chosen one already existed, but all it does when you pick 3 as your option is first print out the line "Type a new name:" and IMMEDIATELY skips to the `FileNotFoundException` catch, completely bypassing the code that should allow the user to enter a new name, but I have NO idea why. Any suggestions?

```
            System.out.println("Type a new name:");                 
            String retryName = keyboard.nextLine();                                     
            try
            {
                outputStream = new PrintWriter(retryName);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error creating file " + retryName + "!");
                System.out.println("The program will now close.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            while (inputStream.hasNextLine())
            {
                outputStream.println(inputStream.nextLine());                       
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure that it immediately goes to catch ? what if you put a stdout before creating PrintWriter ?

Comment: Hi DragonWolf. I edited the title of your question, I don't know why you thought that this has to do with the switch/case structure. What I'd do in your case is try to re-factor the switch/case into an if/else if you suspected it. This looks like a classic scanner token consumption issue. Even before, I'm still not sure I liked the title very much. "Case not working as it should" in switch statement gives me very little indication of what you think is going wrong. I'd also suggest you try to isolate such issues by removing choice and making sure that the code executes if it's the only case.

Comment: (Cont) one such debugging option would be to run the code with a debugger (here is an eclipse tutorial! http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html ) Which would show you the state of variables during execution. Last but not least, best of luck :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the retryName before your try / catch;  what does retryName contain? I bet you it contains a new line that you are NOT capturing as part of the code that lets the user pick the option earlier in your code.

Comment: Actually ya that had to be the issue, I went ahead and made sure it would be empty before it accepted the user input and it worked great! Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @DragonWolf it has nothing to do with the if/else structure, or wheter you are using switch/case.  I think that the issue as as I explained, and it's better expressed by Anthony Accioly below, Do what his code says, if it works please accept HIS answer.

Answer (score 4):

As, Ahmed suggested, you are probably using methods such as `next` and `nextInt`and then forgetting to discard the line terminator before calling `nextLine`.

Try this as a workaround:

```
keyboard.nextLine(); // discard the line break 
String retryName = keyboard.nextLine();
```